# Can't get the selected value of the viewdata dropdownlist to my controller action?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am having trouble getting the selected value of the `DropDownList` to my controller. The string I search is passed to the controller, but the selected value of the dropdown list is not.

#### Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
    items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Movies", Value = "0", Selected = true });
    items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Tv Seires", Value = "1" });
    items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Cast", Value = "2" });
    items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "All", Value = "3" });
    ViewData["Options"] = items;
    return View();
}
```

#### View

```
<div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-btn search-panel">
        @Html.DropDownList("Options",ViewData["Options"]as SelectList, new { @class = "btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle", @id = "search_dropdown" })
    </div>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.searchValue,new{htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control", @id="search_input",placeholder="Search term..."}})
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <input type="submit" value="&#x1f50d;" class="btn btn-secondary" id="search_button" />
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: You're attempting to create a search here, right? (add that to the question) the dropdown is composed of categories and in this code you're providing - it is displaying and populating the dropdown as expected, but it is not passed back to your controller when you do some action as the user - like submit the search, is that correct? hench this is a control view state consideration?

Comment: correct @BrettCaswell. Thanks for the edit but i found the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider putting it inside a form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @Html.DropDownList("Options",ViewData["Options"]as SelectList, new { @class = "btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle", @id = "search_dropdown" })

    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.searchValue,new{htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control", @id="search_input",placeholder="Search term..."}})

    <input type="submit" value="&#x1f50d;" class="btn btn-secondary" id="search_button" />
}
```

Comment: OR...  Use DtopDownListFor with a Model.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I found the solution later, i created a dictionary and bound it to a property in my model.